# Calculate inside of an animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well I am  going to keep this one short. Let's start with my code:

```
$container.animate({
    paddingBottom: //315% + 100px
});
```

What I have here is a short bit of code, which sould animate a 315% + 100px padding-bottom. The problem is how can I make jQuery calculate this. I tried things as "calc(315% + 100px)" like it works in css, but it doesn't fix the problem in jQuery. Also I tried multiple thing with variables, +-signs and "". Still I can't find a solution. I hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

ps: don't worry about $container it's a working variable

Comment: You're looking for 315% of what?

Comment: I am looking for a padding bottom of 315% + 100px like I said, an explanation for this is not important (I am learning)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom), when setting padding to percentages, it's always based on the containing elements width

Knowing that, you need the parent elements width * 3.15 + 100

```
$container.animate({
    paddingBottom: ($container.parent().width() * 3.15) + 100
});
```